# NoNullAllowedException in DateTimePicker

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm working on a small application. I want to set today's value as the default value to the datetimepicker. Therefore used the `form_load` event and set the date like this:

```
DateDateTimePicker.Value = Date.Today
```

If I select a date from the picker it works fine. But if I don't it shows a null exception when saves it.

The exception occurs in

```
Me.SaleBindingSource.EndEdit()
```

Exception is

```
'System.Data.NoNullAllowedException'
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, and to show the code that makes you say "it shows a null exception when saves it". You probably mean a "NullReferenceException". In that case, note that almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have 'System.Data.NoNullAllowedException' and it occurs in 'Me.SaleBindingSource.EndEdit()'

Comment: Your call to EndEdit() commits the changes, and one of the committed values is null

Comment: Yes. Thank u. Value is the date value. If i keep it default I get the error msg. :-(

Comment: Is there some other variable which is dependent on a value being picked in the DTP rather than the value of the DTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant have null in datetimepicker but set it to datetime.min value and tgen perform validations